# jQuery Cycle- How to animate pagers according to the current slideshow index

Tags: jquery, plugins, indexing, cycle, pager

**Here's what I have:**
I have 5 sliding photos on the page, and there are the pagers 1-5 below the sliding photos. I want to show only 3 pagers at a time, so the 4th and 5th pagers are hidden right now. You can click on the "Next" button to animate the div that contains the pagers to show the 4th and 5th, click on "Prev" button and you go back showing 1st-3rd pagers.

**Here's what I want to achieve but don't know how...**
How do I make the div that contains all pagers to move left to show the 4th and 5th pagers when the slideshow slides to the 4th photo?? Meaning when the slideshow reaches the 4th photo, how do I make that div to move the way just like as if I clicked on the "Next" button?? (And when the slide goes back to the 1st photo, the pagers should move again so it's showing the 1st-3rd pager once again.)

I have no idea which part of the script can let me know which slide is currently active. If I know,  I guess I can trigger the animation of div when the 4th one is active...

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Cycle Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx:     'turnDown',
        speed:  'fast',
        pager:  '#nav',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
            // return sel string for existing anchor
            return '#nav li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
        }
    });
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#next_control').click(function() {
        var c = $('#nav_content');
        var pos = c.position();
        var w = c.width();
        var status = w + pos.left;
        var dif = w - 190;
        var x = w + dif;
        if (status > 190) {
            c.stop().animate({
                left: pos.left - 180
            }, 500)
        };
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#prev_control').click(function() {
        var c = $('#nav_content');
        var pos = c.position();
        if (pos.left < 0) {
            c.stop().animate({
                left: pos.left + 180
            }, 500)
        };
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
}
 #slideshow {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
#bot {
    background-color: #CCC;
    height: 50px;
    width: 290px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
#nav_content #nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    height:50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}


#bot #nav_wrapper {
    background-color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 190px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#bot #previous {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
#bot #next {
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
#bot #nav_wrapper #nav_content {
    height: 50px;
    width: 310px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="slideshow">
<img src="img/beach1.jpg" />
<img src="img/beach2.jpg" />
<img src="img/beach3.jpg" />
<img src="img/beach4.jpg" />
<img src="img/beach5.jpg" />
</div>

<div id="bot">
<div id="previous"><a id="prev_control" href="#">Prev</a></div>
<div id="nav_wrapper">
<div id="nav_content"> 
  <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#"><img src="img/beach1.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="img/beach2.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="img/beach3.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="img/beach4.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="img/beach5.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="next"><a id="next_control" href="#">Next</a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery cycle plugin website:

When using the pager option, the genrated navigation elements are simply anchors. So if you 
set the pager option like so:
pager: '#nav'
you can style the anchors like this:

```
#nav a { background-color: #fc0 }
```

In addition, the navigation element for the active slide is given the class activeSlide so that it can be styled uniquely.

The pager in the example above is styled like this:

```
#nav a { border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #fc0; text-decoration: none; margin: 0 5px; padding: 3px 5px;  }
#nav a.activeSlide { background: #ea0 }
#nav a:focus { outline: none; }
```